# Ruby CSV parsing from Excel with multilingual document

Tags: ruby, csv, character-encoding, multilingual

I have a csv document exported from Excel and containing both english and non-english (russian) letters.

I've managed to open it with

```
CSV.open @tmp, "rb:ISO-8859-1", {col_sep: ";"}
```

but it read russian symbols as `\xCE\xF1\xF2\xE0\xEB\xFC\xED\xFB\xE5 \xE7\xE0\xEF\xF7` etc.
I've try "rb:ISO-8859-1:UTF-8" but get "ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8", same as csv.open runned without mode.

How this could be fixed? Also, how I could find 'mode' argument options - I couldn't understand from docs where it is described.

Main environment is Ubuntu server, if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

try using this format

```
r:ISO-8859-15:UTF-8
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like it have some tune to the locale of customer when save data. For several files CP-1251 works fine. Not sure how to test file to guess original encoding.